# Can't turn off onboard LED on Pi Zero anymore

Tags: pi-zero, board-leds, activity-led

I used to be able to turn off the green on-board LED with the following commands:

```
echo none | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/class/leds/led0/brightness
```

This no longer works, however. What's the new procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to fight with the kernel (you will always lose) set it properly using Device Tree:-

Include

```
dtparam=act_led_trigger=none
```

in `config.txt`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to change the brightness as well? For example, set its value to 128.